# Why do I have to specify the subnet broadcast address?

Tags: subnet, ipv4, cisco-catalyst

When configuring the management IP address of managed Cisco switches, I have to specify the broadcast address of the management network next to their address AND their netmask. Of course this is always the last address of the subnet.

Why do I have to specify it? Why doesn't it calculate the address on its own? Are there situations or reasons to use a different one?

Comment: Long ago certain TCP implementations used all 0's in the host portion of the broadcast address - don't know if anybody does this anymore or even if this requirement is to accommodate those legacy broadcasts,

Comment: I haven't seen that in a long time. Which hardware and software are you seeing this on?

Comment: Various C3560G running 15.02 SE8.